# Set default option in select menu without saving it to the model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a select element that is populated using ng-options.

```
    <select class="form-control form-group col-sm-2"  ng-model="defaulObject" 
ng-options="object.description for object in allObjects"></select>
```

Now, I would like to add default option field that is saying something like 'Please select an object', and I don't want that to be saved in the model(defaultObject), because that's just a string. Is this possible to achieve with AngularJS ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<select ...>
    <option value="">Please select something</option>
</select>
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ben1729/hLb2h6rk/

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want a placeholder. Then it would be:

```
<select ...>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select     an object</option>
```